# Making a mixin of interfaces in Typescript

Tags: interface, typescript

I have a class with over 80 methods, and each method accepts an object containing some defined interface.

```typescript
class Stuff {
   /* many more */
   getAccount(req: IAccount, callback: ICallback) {
      return this._call('getAccount', req, callback);
   }

   getIds(req: IIDs, callback: ICallback) {
      return this._call('getIds', req, callback);
   }
   /* many more */
}
```

pretty 'boring' stuff, since it's just mapping to the underlaying `_call` method and making it type safe for each of the methods.

But sometimes these `req` param objects are made up from 2 interfaces or more, and instead of creating another interface for each time there's an "awkward", like this:

```typescript
export interface ILoled extends IAccount {
   loled: boolean;
}

export interface IRofloled extends ILoled {
   rofled: boolean;
}

class Stuff {
  getLols(req: ILoled){
  }

  getRofls(req: IRofloled){
  }
}
```

is there any way I can just put it as an "inline" mixin of interfaces inside the method parameter list? like (which obviously don't work):

```typescript
class Stuff {
  getMoreStuff(req: <{} extends IAccount, ITime>) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that you do have to declare a super-interface.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes you can, [as of Typescript 1.6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6.aspx).  Called ***Intersection types***, use the `&` operator to combine types.

```
function extend<T, U>(first: T, second: U): T & U {
  let result = <T & U> {};
  for (let id in first) {
    result[id] = first[id];
  }

  for (let id in second) {
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      result[id] = second[id];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var x = extend({ a: "hello" }, { b: 42 });
x.a; // works
x.b; // works
```

Comment: As in 2022, TS 4.7 reports error `Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'number'.` like in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB5WWAJgHgCoA0iAqgHwAUwMATgM5QBcihityECWTxAlE3ogBkJRAG8AsAChEiADbIoiaslohZigLyJ8QkqTEBfANxSZwONUTl5imFkQwkVOlB5jTMpSrVQA2nYBdRC1nen8sAJNpRAMpD3NLawUHe0dWdk43CWiZGGArAEJlVXUAOgALAENaAHkAdzAABWo4AAdkaigAT3I7HiyPTy8Sv0Dg9I5scMjBmI9Y6OUoEGokYp8ohakAN0rLVHG0DGxyUURKpgAicuRZWThLmKIzgCMmABYAJhieKNRSypGRAAemBiDqFgA1rQpP8XkDQeCobREEA)

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way I can just put it as an "inline" mixin of interfaces inside the method parameter list

No. You cannot *extend* an interface inline